# Trying to gather and display visitors' comments on the same html page

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need your help: I'm trying to gather visitors' comments through a form on an html page and then display them at the bottom of the same html page. I can gather the comments and write them onto a database using a php script, but the comments are displayed on the php page, and not on my original html page. I haven't found any relevant answer in the forums I have visited so far. Your help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

1. html page (where the comments are gathered through a form, and where I would like to display the all gathered comments as well):

   Your comments:

   Your name:  Your email address:
2. Script: post_comment.php:

   ```
   $db_sitename ="xxx";
   $hostname    = "xxx";
   $username    = "xxx";
   $dbname      = "xxx";
   $password    = "xxx";
   $usertable   = "xxx";

   $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
   mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
   $sql="INSERT INTO $usertable (Comments, Full_Name, Email) VALUES ('$_POST[comments]','$_POST[full_name]','$_POST[email]')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo "1 record added";

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable");

   echo "<table border='1'>  <tr>  <th>Commentaires:</th>  <th>Nom:</th> </tr>";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Full_Name'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";

   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
   ```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer supported and the **deprecation** process has started. For alternative, more secure solutions take a look at **mysqli** or **PDO**.

Answer (score 0):

here are the links to what u r looking 4.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/147416-display-the-users-comments-on-same-page/

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/141184/show-results-on-same-page#

Comment: Those tutorials are extremely old and use deprecated ... everything. @XavierLederer: be very careful with those, and at least use mysqli or PDO. PS: Fix your spelling man, it's not a timesaver to write "u r looking 4" instead of "you are looking for", and it's not readable.

Comment: alrite thx for your response. will make sure i remember that and yeah u are right in saying that the links are old. i was just trying to convey an idea here, nothing more than that. just trying to make sure the basic framework is right as in what goes where to achieve this. Once u have the blueprint for the functions it might not be really hard to replace deprecated code with newer libraries but yes indeed you are right in pointing that out..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all the existing comments on the html-page, you need to use javascript and ajax to fetch the data from the database and show it on the page.

The more usual way of doing this would be to use a php-page for both the form and the existing comments. - then if you want, you can also add in some ajax to dynamically update the page.

But also remember be warned - if you want to make this as some kind of public page, you should do some serious analyses of the incoming comments to check for all kind of potential problems, especially, but probably not limited to html, javascript and sql.

Answer (score 0):

what you mean  comments are displayed on the php page, and not on my original html page. you can use `include"php.page"`

Answer (score 0):

The comment should be saved on the database via ajax and jquery so that you wont have to use submit, because it will be quite annoying to have the page reload everytime a comment is posted.

On the other hand, the real time fetching of comments would be using ajax and jquery. Create a function that will fetch the comments from the database and call it for like every 2 sec or so. and append the output on the existing thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Thanks to your guidance I found an answer to my question: instead of referring to an external php-page in my form () I will in fact simply refer to my initial page, the one that contains all the html text, using this code: " method="post">. This allows to keep html text and the php scripting code on the same page, and therefore solve my problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of you are done with this, and feel your solution is the best. vote/accept the answer.